# change key in python dict and print only the key value with value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to manipulate a dict as:

```
op = {'File:Directory': '/var/tmp/Mkbib/Trial2', 'PDF:Title': 'Antiferromagnetic-ferromagnetic transition in FeRh', 'PDF:Author': 'V. L. Moruzzi and P. M. Marcus', 'File:FileSize': '636 kB', 'File:FileInodeChangeDate': '2016:08:13 19:45:15+02:00'}

fields = ["author",  "year",  "journal", "title", "publisher"]
new_op = {}
for field in fields:
    # new_op = dict((field, value) for key, value in op.items() if field in key.lower())
    new_op[field] = value for key, value in op.items() if field in key.lower())
    print(new_op)
```

My goal is to change `op`'s key to matching(if any) `field from fields`, and create new_op with the new key, and value if it has  a matching key.

So, in the above example, my new_op should be:

```
new_op = {'title': 'Antiferromagnetic-ferromagnetic transition in FeRh', 'author': 'V. L. Moruzzi and P. M. Marcus'}
```

The commented line is working, but obviously creating new dict for each item., and also printing for all loop, as obvious.

Comment: You could just create a new key and delete the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension here.

```
op = {
    'File:Directory': '/var/tmp/Mkbib/Trial2',
    'PDF:Title': 'Antiferromagnetic-ferromagnetic transition in FeRh',
    'PDF:Author': 'V. L. Moruzzi and P. M. Marcus',
    'File:FileSize': '636 kB',
    'File:FileInodeChangeDate': '2016:08:13 19:45:15+02:00'
}

fields = [
    'author',
    'year',
    'journal',
    'title',
    'publisher'
]

new_op = {
    field: value for field in fields
    for key, value in op.items() if field in key.lower()
}

print(new_op)  # {'title': 'Antiferromagnetic-ferromagnetic transition in FeRh', 'author': 'V. L. Moruzzi and P. M. Marcus'}
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehension creates a new dictionary which OP explicitly doesn't want.

Comment: I read the OP's statement as not wanting to create a new key *per item*, not for the entire thing.